# Inconsistent binding when piping DirectoryInfo objects

Tags: powershell

I've often used a construct similar to this (using aliases for brevity):

```
gci -ad | %{$_ | gci}
```

which works fine. But when trying to help another user on this forum, I found that the following *doesn't* work:

```
gci -ad | %{$_.Parent | gci}
```

throws the following error for each iteration:

```
gci : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\keith\Documents\Documents' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:25
+ gci -ad | %{$_.Parent | gci}
+                         ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\keith\Documents\Documents:Stri
   ng) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemC
   ommand
```

even though:

```
gci -ad | %{$_.GetType() -eq $_.Parent.GetType()}
```

produces a scrennfull of `True`.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with parameter binding, but would like to understand the apparent inconsistancy....

Comment: Not really inconsistent if you're passing it the parent directory of the listed objects, `C:\Users\keith\Documents`.  So, it's coercing the name, since it wasn't successful in coercing the object into `-LiteralPath`, into a string to append to the path you're executing from. `$_` would be the listed items from `gci` whereas `$_.Parent` would just be -*as the name implies*- the parent folder: `Documents`. Hence "`'C:\Users\keith\Documents\Documents' `"

Comment: change `%{$_.Parent | gci}` to `gci -ad | %{$_.Parent.fullname | gci}` // unfortunate for windows pwsh as per usual. works fine in newer pwsh

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, that would just be relisting `.\Documents` over and over again, unless that's the intentions of the OP; *per folder listed*. Otherwise, `gci -ad | gci` should suffice.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala pretty much what the code is doing is relisting the contents of the parent folder so what I posted is how it would work in windows powershell that is failing for OP.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, ahhh, I see lol I was going based of his working (*first*) example. Looks like you were just correcting what would work for the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to see what's happening is to emulate the binding with a test function, but the issue is, as you might know in .NET Framework when a `DirectoryInfo` instance is coerced into a string the result will be it's `.Name` property value as opposed to .NET where the coercion results in the `.FullName` property.

Since the object returned by calling the `.Parent` property does not have the ETS Property `.PSPath`, the input object will be bound the the `Path` Parameter and coerced to a string.

Assuming you have both versions of PowerShell, you can try the following to see the difference:

```
function Test-Binding {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Items')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Items', Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        ${Path},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralItems', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]]
        ${LiteralPath}
    )

    process {
        $PSBoundParameters
        $PSBoundParameters.Clear()
    }
}

(Get-Item .), (Get-Item .).Parent | Test-Binding
```

Comment: Nice; just a quibble: `.Parent` indeed _always_ stringifies by name only in WinPS, but for `DirectoryInfo` instances in general it depends on the specifics of the `Get-ChildItem` call (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375)).

Comment: @mklement0 the behavior in .NET Framework is quite enigmatic, not sure what were they thinking. The fact that `[string] [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] $pwd.Path` outputs the FullName and `[string] ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] $pwd.Path).Parent` outputs the Name is absurd really

Comment: Didn't even give me time to market this as "Answer"? I'm insulted! :D The one thing I was missing is that `$_.Parent` lacks the `PSpath` property. Thanks.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, agreed. I _think_ it came down to the name / path that was passed to the _constructor_ of the instance, and in the case of `.Parent` the instance is seemingly constructed by name only.

Comment: @KeithMiller, see [GitHub issue #4347](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4347) for background information.

Comment: I get it now. Ran into similar confusion a few years ago with registry keys returned from `Get-ChildItem` vs. those returned from the `RegistryKey.OpenSubkey()` method...

Comment: @mklement0 if the instance of `.Parent` was constructed by name only then `.FullName` would resolve to the value of `[IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` instead of the correct absolute path, which is not the case. `.FullName` of a `.Parent` instance does resolve properly, so it is not constructed by Name in my opinion.

Comment: We're talking about _stringification_ (`.ToString()` return value), not _property values_ (`.Name` and `.FullName` _do_ work properly, always, even in WinPS).

Comment: I see what you meam, I'm just confused what you meant by "and in the case of `.Parent` the instance is seemingly constructed by name only." @mklement0 if it was constructed by name then calling `.FullName` on that instance shouldn't resolve properly unless I'm missing something

Comment: Yeah, with `.Parent` it is basically an _implementation detail_ as to how that instance is constructed _behind the scenes_, and in WinPS / .NET Framework this implementation details leaks out in the `.ToString()` behavior. To be clear: It was always a bad idea to base `.ToString()` behavior on the instance's construction details, and, fortunately, PS Core / .NET (Core) did away with that.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: Please forgive my earlier comment about "... marking as Answer...". I answer frequently but ask infrequently. When I saw the gray checknark, I didn't pay attention to the color and assumed your answer had already been marked as Answer. I've marked and upvoted now.

Comment: no worries @KeithMiller happy the answer was helpful

Comment: Just saw your update: the intent and implementation was always to _internally_ resolve to to a full path (even though no existence check is made); e.g., `([io.directoryinfo] 'imaginary').fullname` (but note that resolving is performed against the _process_'s working directory, not PowerShell's).

Comment: @mklement0 yes, it's the same as `[io.path]::Combine([io.directory]::GetCurrentDirectory(), 'imaginary')` which had me confused, not sure how did the make for `.Parent` to resolve properly if it was constructed by name: `[io.directoryinfo] ([io.directoryinfo] $pwd.Path).Parent.Name` then the `.FullName` property of that instance would depend on `[io.directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` at the moment it was instantiated however that's not the case

Comment: It is `[io.directoryinfo] $pwd.Path)` that implies the `.FullName` value of that instance, and the `.Parent` property instance is constructed _relative to it_ (irrespective of the process working dir.). (If `$pwd.Path` is based on a _PowerShell-only_ drive, however, problems can ensue.)

Comment: But at its not, isn't it about binding and a"pure" .NET object and the"enhanced" PS version with its "PS..." NoteProperties? The default parameterSet wants to bind `-LireralParh` to `$_.PSPath`, and when that doesn't exist , things go south...

Comment: @KeithMiller, that is _also_ a problem, but a _separate_ one. It (typically) wouldn't be a problem if the `.ToString()` value of `.Parent` yielded its `.FullName` property value, as it does in PowerShell (Core). That said, as the answer notes, the absence of a `.PSPath` property causes _string_-based binding to the `-Path` parameter, making the input paths subject to interpretation as [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).